# Simple project/time/task management software any ideas?

Tags: task-management, project-management

As I am trying to learn new stuff using MOOCs, it is getting harder to see clear overall picture of past/current/future status.
Is there a simple software for personal project management(online/offline) that supports:

- adding project/course(name, start and end time, mid points)
- updated/manually progress(like 15%)
- see all project past/current/future in timeline
- add date and expected progress for that date
- user-friendly UI

Something like this:

```
 01.10.2016      |                                                01.11.2016
                 |
   Intro to Algorithms
   Problem set 1 |  Problem set 2    Problem set 3
   05.10.2016    |  12.10.2016       19.10.2016
   [19%]==========>-*----------------*
                 |
                 |  C++ for C programmers
                 |  Homework 1       Homework 2
                 |  12.10.2016       19.10.2016
                 |  [1%]=>-----------*---------
                 |
                 |
```

Comment: Look into a few agile project management tools. Agile is software development methodology, but some of their ideas are equally applicable to other projects, and the layout for project management is very similar to what you ask. Of the top of my head, i know there's Jira, but I've never used it myself, so can't really recommend or critique it.

Comment: Thanks for the comment but JIRA is not what i  am looking for. I just want to put "projects" to timeline. Timeline is critical for me.